# Why do USA transceivers limit transmit to 430-450MHz?

Tags: united-states, band-plan, 70cm-band

The [FCC table of frequency allocations](http://transition.fcc.gov/oet/spectrum/table/fcctable.pdf) clearly states on page 27 that the Amateur allocation for 70cm is 420-450MHz, but I've seen a lot of transceivers that limit transmit to 430-450MHz.

Why is this?

Answer (score 8):

It is probably due to the fact that Canada does not include 420-430MHz in their 70cm band plan. The [United States agrees not to allow their amateurs to interfere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/70-centimeter_band#Band_allocation), by restricting 420-430MHz [north of Line A and east of Line C](http://transition.fcc.gov/oet/info/maps/canline/canline.html).  (See also FCC Title 47 Part 97.303.m which I can't find a good way to link to.)

When the manufacturer decides to restrict 420-430MHz, then the transceiver can be sold in both the US and Canada, and US customers are unlikely to mistakenly infringe.